# Are all my sources of income considered when calculating the repayment of my student loan?

Tags: united-kingdom, loans, repayment, student

Actually, I have two questions.

1. I have a student loan income-based repayment, from my studies in the UK. Are any other income sources rather than my salary considered?. For example, a rent I get from a flat I own and let out. What about other investments like, shares?.
2. If i am not able to make any repayments, or only a very small amount and after 20 years my loan is forgiven, is that forgiven balance taxed? i assume that the balance forgiven is not the initial borrowed, but the final result of 25 years of compounding interest.

Comment: You should say what type of student loan you have (when did you take it out?) as there have been different schemes over the years